How to prevent windows stacking top each other in Python
I basically use os module for opening new windows in python but they just open top of each other but i want them to have an effect like sliding by changing the position whenever a new one opens.
import os
for i in range(10):
    os.startfile(cmd.exe)

I don't want them to stack on top of each other.

Window management in this case is handled by the operating system, not Python.
